# Smoothly keyframing a wheel to decelerate from point A to B

Tags: video-editor, davinci-resolve

I am trying to accomplish this:
I have a transparent image, a wheel that can be rotated and moved in DaVinci Resolve (that's what I am using but I guess a solution to this could apply in any editor).

[image]

I want this wheel to come from off the screen in motion, and stop at the end of the screen without any jerky movement.... but it should decelerate as it goes along. Smoothly. How should I accomplish this? I've given multiple tries to this and failed. There's always some jerky movement. I think it is a matter of getting things mathematically right lol.

Following are the transform controls we can see in Resolve, for reference (these are not values I've set for this wheel, just to show you the two controls I was trying to modify. Position and rotation angle.

[image]

Comment: I have done this successfully in DaVinci Resolve but had to ballpark a lot of things and adjust with trial and error. I am just curious if there is a way to get this right in a way that even if I had to change any parameter like rotation angle or distance, it wouldn't mess up my whole timeline. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For good or bad, in Davinci it's all about maths. Since you want to move the wheel you will change position x/y and rotation, as you mentioned. But you will have to add time points and make the calculations (i.e. if you want to speed up/slow down, change move/rotation direction etc).

For example you want to have the motion for 5 secs, 1 full rotation lasts 1 secs. So you are gone have something like that:

```
time=0s x=-200, rotation=0
time=1s, rotation=360
time=2s, rotation=720
time=2.5s, x=0
time=3s, rotation=1080
time=4s, rotation=1440
time=5s, x=200,rotation=1800
```

[image: Time points are showed with the red rhombus and it's changing during the time]

I hope to help you out a little.. :)